# Dell poweredge 1900 Dban drives individually

Tags: dban

I have 6 SATA HDDs connected to the server.  Is there a way to dBan each disk individually.  As of right now the controller creates a virtual drive and when the dBan is initialized it only wipes the virtual drive.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can enter the RAID BIOS, configure all the drives to be independant (neither hot spares nor part of any array - terminology varies).  They should then be expressed to the OS underlying DBAN as SATA drives.